# xa transaction with CMT

Tags: jboss5.x, distributed-transactions

Recently I am involved in dealing with distributed transaction with JBoss 5.1 wherein Container Managed Transaction is used. But my worry is I am not understanding how different xa-resources are participating in the distributed transaction managed by JBossTS transaction manager. Basically I am looking for what are the transaction boundaries. And where I should put my code which I want to be executed as part of the transaction ? And also how container would understand which bean belongs to which xa-datasource.

I have already googled and tried to get something from JBoss documentation but couldn't find anything useful.

I already know how to configure datasources and transaction manager.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. It was answered by Wolf-Dieter Fink. It's [here](http://community.jboss.org/message/782594#)